# Cannot store value in SESSION for second time after user logout in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a log-in script for user login. The user information is stored in the MYSQL database. When i login for first time, it stores the information in the session and display the welcome message. But when i log-out and try to log-in again, the session array display empty although it is logged in.

Here are my codes:

**reservation.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once("./includes/config_db.php");
$error1=array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if (preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,8}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['user_id'])))) {
        $e = escape_data($_POST['user_id']);
    } else {
        $e = FALSE;
        $error1['user_id']="UserID Required!";
    }

    if (preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['password'])))) {
        $p = escape_data($_POST['password']);
    } else {
        $p = FALSE;
        $error1['password']="Password Required!";
    }


    if($e && $p){
        $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE(user_id='$e' AND password=SHA('$p')) AND active='NULL'";
        $results=mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM);
            mysql_free_result($results);
            $_SESSION['name']=$row[0];
            $_SESSION['department']=$row[1];
            $_SESSION['email']=$row[2];
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$row[4];
            $_SESSION['phone']=$row[5];
            $_SESSION['pre']=$row[8];

            //create second token
            $tokenid=rand(10000,9999999);
            $query2="UPDATE r_users SET token='$tokenid' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
            $result2=mysql_query($query2);
            $_SESSION['tokenid']=$tokenid;
            session_regenerate_id();
            mysql_close();
            header("Location:local.php");
            exit();

        }else
        {
            $error1['active']="Either your Account is inactive or Email/Password is incorrect";
             mysql_close();
        }
    }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Reservation System</title>
<!--Link to external files-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reservation.css"></link>

</head>

<body class="body">
    <div id="mainHeader">
        <?php include('includes/ers_header.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">  
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <?php include('includes/ers_nav.php');?>
    <h3>Member Login</h3>
<form id="login" action="reservation.php" method="post">
<?php if(!empty($error1['active'])) echo '<p><font color="red">'.$error1['active'].'</font></p>'; ?>
<label for="userid">User ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="user_id" <?php  if (!empty($error1['user_id'])){ echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['user_id']).'"';} ?>  autofocus />
<?php  if (!empty($error1['user_id'])){ echo '<p><font color="red">'.$error1['user_id'].'</font></p>';} ?>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<?php  if (!empty($error1['password'])){ echo '<p><font color="red">'.$error1['password'].'</font></p>';} ?>
<button class="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ers_header.php:**

```
<h1>XXXXXXXXXX</h1>
<h2>YYYYYYYYYYY</h2>
<h2>ZZZZZZZZZZZZ</h2>
<?php
    require_once("./includes/config_db.php");
    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        $sql="SELECT token FROM users WHERE(user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { // A match was made.
            $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
            mysql_free_result($result);
            mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.

            if($_SESSION['tokenid'] == $row[0]){
                echo '<p>Welcome';
                echo "&nbsp;{$_SESSION['name']}";
                $loggedin=1;
            }else{
                $loggedin=0;
            }
        }
    }

      if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) AND (substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] AND $loggedin,-10)!='logout.php')){
      echo'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
      echo'</p>';
      }
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require_once("./includes/config_db.php");

   if ( !isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ) {
       header("Location: reservation.php");
       exit(); 
   } else { 
       $_SESSION = array(); // Destroy the variables.
       session_destroy(); // Destroy the session itself.
       setcookie( session_name(), ", time()-300, '/', ", 0 ); // Destroy the cookie.
       header("Location:reservation.php");
   }
```

I don't know what is the problem. I have tried a lot but couldn't find it out. Please can anyone figure out my mistake.

Comment: Why your making session equals to array? Its enough to call session destroy. Also you shouldnt look in logout if the name is set, just destroy the session andheader away. And wwhy your using cookies?

Comment: do as @T_01 told and also just print_r($_SESSION) in header and show the output here.

Comment: your code looks right.i haven't found any error in code.just remove setcookie( session_name(), ", time()-300, '/', ", 0 ); line from your code and run it.may be it causes problem.

Comment: stop using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated, use mysqli/PDO instead...they are better and safer

Comment: I have the same problem, but with cookies.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It is solved now. May be the issue was due to cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You really should only need to unset the $_SESSION array, not destroy the session and cookie data, try removing those lines, but also:

mysql_affected_rows should be mysql_num_rows

also this line of code is incorrect:

```
$query2="UPDATE r_users SET token='$tokenid' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
```

`$_SESSION[user_id]` should be `$_SESSION["user_id"]` and you should wrap it in {}. PHP probably gives warnings about this.

and this line of code is strange:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) AND (substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] AND $loggedin,-10)!='logout.php')
```

is the `$loggedin,-10` really supposed to be in substr?